# mysql query data insertion through php

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "test";
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Connected successfully";
$value1=$_POST['txtname'];
$value2=$_POST['cellnumber'];
$value3=$_POST['dist'];
$value4=$_POST['specialization'];
$value5=$_POST['membername'];
$value6=$_POST['date'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO students (StudentName, CellNumber, District, Specialization, PromotionMember, Date)
VALUES ('$value1', '$value2', '$value3', '$value4', '$value5', '$value6')";
if (!mysqli_query($sql)) { 
die ('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
else
{ 
echo ("معلومات ارایه شده شما ثبت شد");
header("Location: register.html");
}
mysqli_close();
?>
```

connection is successfull but data insertion is getting error on line 23 which is (if (!mysqli_query($sql)) { )
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4Zj9.jpg)

Comment: Do you understand what is written in error text?

Comment: Did you try to find a manual for `mysqli_query`? Here, I did it for you http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [*SQL injection*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1).

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a programming-service. Did you checked your error-logs?

Answer (score 1):

Your query doesn't run because you are using the `MySQLi` function wich need 2 parameters to execute your query.

So instead of

```
mysqli_query($sql)
```

you have to do:

```
mysqli_query($conn, $sql)
```

Your code also looks vulnerable to SQL Injections, so you want to know how to escape the strings in [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php). I recommend you to use [prepared](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) statements.
I hope this will help!

Comment: Thank you I make changes and that problem solved, but still its not inserting the data

Connected successfully Error:

Comment: My error is exactly (Connected Successfully error:) and its on line 23 which is (die ('Error: ' . mysql_error());)

Comment: @GhufranAtaie Change `mysql_error()` to `mysqli_error($conn)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code...

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO students (StudentName,CellNumber, District, Specialization, PromotionMember,      Date)VALUES ('$value1', '$value2', '$value3', '$value4', '$value5', '$value6')";
$q=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
if (!$q) { 
die ('Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
}else{header("Location: register.html");}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This code..

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO students (StudentName, CellNumber, District, Specialization, PromotionMember, Date)
VALUES ('$value1', '$value2', '$value3', '$value4', '$value5', '$value6')";
$qw=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

if($qw)

{

header("Location: register.html");

}
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this code"? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.